# [x86 ASM]Running a graphical debugger with arguments

Tags: debugging, assembly

You'd think that this would be easier to achieve. I'm attempting to understand a small program called hexdump1, from "Assembly Language Step by Step 3rd edition" and it requires that I pass it an argument like this:

> hexdump1 < input.txt

I'm extremely new and struggle to understand what is going on while using gdb. To make it easier in the beginning I'm using EDB debugger. Under the Options
tab there is an option to set application arguments. I've set the arguments as:

> < input.txt

and

> input.txt

But once I step through to the part of the code where it reads input, it then just runs all the way through and I can't debug it anymore. I find it hard to believe that graphical debuggers simply can't debug an application with arguments as that would make there use **extremely** limited.

Also, the code runs just fine and does exactly what it's supposed to in the terminal. Is there a better graphical debugger for my purposes? Thank you.

Comment: How about Ollydbg?  http://www.ollydbg.de/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the `< input.txt` part was never meant to be an argument to hexdump1.  Apparently hexdump1 has been written to read from the standard input (and write to the standard output, I presume.)

So, the `< input.txt` part is some text that you type in the command line and gets parsed by the command interpreter (cmd.exe under windows) and it tells the command interpreter to launch hexdump1 with its standard input stream redirected to read from that file.  So, hexdump1 ends up reading that file without knowing it.

Now, when launching your hexdump1 from within the debugger, the debugger does not make any attempt to interpret the `< input.txt` part, so it passes it as a parameter to hexdump1, which ignores it and proceeds to try to read from the standard input. The standard input is empty, so hexdump1 does nothing.

I have no solution to your problem other than:

1. Modifying hexdump1 to read an actual file whose filename is passed as a parameter instead of reading from standard input
2. Messing with the options of the debugger to see if there is any way to specify an actual file to redirect the standard input.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer. I simply couldn't find any other way then to just learn to become more comfortable with GDB. It seems there is no match for it.